# System76 Oryx Pro does not resume after put into Suspend

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, suspend, 18.04

Everytime I put my System76 Oryx Pro into suspend, it either show a backlit screen with an underscore, or the backlight doesn't turn on and I am left with a black screen of death. I am not the most adept in getting bug reports, or finding out what is causing my computer to be a vegetable after suspend, so I will need some guidance if you need that info. What I can say is the computer has a NVIDIA GeForce GTX 970M, and is on NVIDIA driver version 390.48. I currently have Ubuntu 18.04.11 Bionic Beaver as my primary Operating System. My current kernel is 4.15.0-20-generic. Is there anyway to fix this? Would it be safe to switch to the Nouveau proprietary graphics driver? Having to hard reset my computer each time is getting pretty annoying, and these issues have been occurring since 16.04 LTS on and off.

Comment: Very similar issue to mine that I just posted, and I posted things I have tried to fix it, non of which work. There are so many people having suspend black screen of death bugs out there, why hasn't this been fixed for years?

Comment: @Webeng It has never happened to me at all...not till just a few weeks ago. Alot of people have said that it's NVIDIA being shoddy at making X.org drivers. Would moving to the proprietary drivers (Nouveau) be safe for a System76, I don't want to activate the hidden "Make your BIOS a FRAG" bug. XD